# Connecting GEdit and xdvi

Tags: gedit

I'm trying to connect GEdit and xdvi. I don't use the gedit LaTeX plugin as I don't use LaTeX, but plain TeX.
Well, for the inverse search I compile the TeX file with the "external tools" plugin and the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEXFILE=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
DVIFILE=${TEXFILE/%.*/.dvi}
LOGFILE=${TEXFILE/%.*/.log}
if pdftex -output-format=dvi -src-specials -halt-on-error $TEXFILE; then
    xdvi -editor gedit $DVIFILE
    else gedit $LOGFILE
    fi
```

and the inverse search works quite well.

BUT I'm not able to set the direct search correctly.
I'm trying the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
TEXFILE=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
DVIFILE=${TEXFILE/%.*/.dvi}
xdvi -sourceposition $GEDIT_CURRENT_LINE_NUMBER $DVIFILE
```

but it doesn't work. The error message is "No reference to source file "test.dvi" in DVI file."

Where is the fault?

Comment: If you are happy to use Evince rather then xdvi you can checkout http://askubuntu.com/q/68015/19490

Comment: @N.N. Sorry, it doesn't works. Thanks anyway.